# odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with Unable to find component name

Tags: odbc, unixodbc

I am able to use unixodbc without any problem with my default user. But when I switch to another user, I get an error.

```
[centos@ ~]$ odbcinst -q -s
[ODBC]
[Amazon Redshift DSN 32]

[centos@ ~]$ su ruser
Password:
[ruser@ centos]$ odbcinst -q -s
odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with Unable to find component name.
```

Environment variables are set in both of the users:

```
AMAZONREDSHIFTODBCINI=/etc/amazon.redshiftodbc.ini
ODBCSYSINI=/usr/local/odbc
ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libodbcinst.so
```

Odbc configuration is as follows:

```
[ruser@ centos]$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/odbc /odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/odbc /odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/odbc /ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /etc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

By the way, I don't understand why there are spaces in the above paths. I don't know if there is a way to change them. Any ideas to solve this issue? Overall odbc configuration seems the same in both of the users.

Answer (score 3):

I found the exact same issue on Centos, where I could use the default `centos` user  to connect, but not any other users.

I was able to resolve the issue by copying the working user (or system) `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files across into the home directory of the other user, like so (where I have renamed them to `.odbc.ini` and `.odbcinst.ini` respectively):

**~/.odbc.ini**

```
[MSSQLTest]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Server = tcp:<ip of server>
```

**~/.odbcinst.ini**

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

Finally, I just had to set the following [environment variables](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-unixODBC/) inside my `~/.bashrc` file, and I was able to connect.

```
export ODBCSYSINI="<full path to user folder, which would be the evaluated path of {echo ~}>"
export ODBCINSTINI=".odbcinst.ini"
export ODBCINI="<full path to user folder, which would be the evaluated path of {echo ~}>/.odbc.ini"
```

For some reason, I wasn't able to use `~` to reference the user folders, so I had to manually specify the full user path in the environment variables, and thus my complete `.bashrc` file is simply:

```
export ODBCSYSINI="/home/mitch"
export ODBCINSTINI=".odbcinst.ini"
export ODBCINI="/home/mitch/.odbc.ini"
```

With this setup, I could now run the following and connect successfully:

```
$ isql -v MSSQLTest <sql server username> <sql server password>
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

Comment: Hi @mitchdav. Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately, I can't test it because I don't work in that company anymore :) I even got a `Tumbleweed` badge for asking this question, so I appreciate your answer and effort.